# How to align rectangle to bottom of any device?

Tags: java, android

```
rec.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()/2);
```

It creates the rectangle as expected, I know 0, 0 is x, y but how do I set y to the bottom so it stays at the bottom on all devices with different size?

Comment: Include the layout XML

Answer (score 0):

you haven't given much information, so I'll state my assumptions

the x,y would be the top-left of your shape, so assuming that the canvas is the full height of the device:

x - 0, as you want the shape to start on the left edge, y - the height of the device minus the height of the shape

your code would be

```
int width = canvas.getWidth();
int height = canvas.getHeight()/2;
int x = 0;
int y = canvas.getHeight() - height;

rec.set(x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: Well, I have a rectangle which fills the width and has the height of the screen/2, I want to position it to the bottom of any device, the code you gave won't work, but thanks for replying quick.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think my code won't work. The code given should align the rectangle to the bottom regardless of what you set the height to. For your case (height = screenHeight/2) - your y value will also be screenHeight/2